# Pagination with multi match query

Tags: elasticsearch, pagination

I'm trying to figure out how to accomplish pagination with a multi match query using elasticsearch.

The `scroll` and `search_after` APIs seem like they won't work. `scroll` isn't meant for real time user requests as per [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html). `search_after` requires some unique field per id and requires you to sort on that field as per [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-search-after.html) but when using a multi-match query you're basically sorting by the score.

So, the only thing I've thought of so far is to do the following:

Send back last document id + score and use the score as the sort field. But, this could potentially return duplicate documents if other documents were added in between two queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to paginate the first option is to use `from` and `size` parameter in your query. [The documentation here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-from-size.html)

> Pagination of results can be done by using the from and size
>   parameters. The from parameter defines the offset from the first
>   result you want to fetch. The size parameter allows you to configure
>   the maximum amount of hits to be returned.
>
> Though from and size can be set as request parameters, they can also
>   be set within the search body. from defaults to 0, and size defaults
>   to 10.
>
> Note that from + size can not be more than the index.max_result_window
>   index setting which defaults to 10,000. See the Scroll or Search After
>   API for more efficient ways to do deep scrolling.

If you don't need to paginate over 10k results it's your best choice. The `max_result_window` can be modified, but the performance will decrease as the selected page number will increase.

But of course if some documents are added during your user pagination they will be added and your pagination can be slightly inaccurate.

Comment: How do you handle if new documents were added to the beginning? I.e. 10 new documents were indexed and those documents have the highest score for the query. Then skip and from doesn't work.

Comment: Oops didn't read the last bit of your answer. Yeah, that makes sense. I've just decided to return a max of 500 or 1000 results (since I'm just returning the ids) and having the client paginate over the list of ids.